# Read multiple lines in a text file

Tags: python

I am reading a text file line by line and when I encounter a specific string a want to store the line and the following two lines in a variable.

```
infile = open('file.txt', 'r')

for line in infile:
    if line.startswith('X'):
        3_lines = readlines() 

infile.close()
```

Is there some way I can do this. I have been trying to solve this using next() or readlines(). But I cannot figure out how to get it to work. Any suggestions would be super appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to do? Use `file.readlines()` to read the files lines...

Comment: I want to loop over a text file and when I encounter a specific string I want to write this line and the following three lines to a new text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using lists,

```
results = []

infile = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()

for line in infile:
    if line.startswith('t'):
        index = infile.index(line)

        for times in range(0, 3):
            results.append(infile[index + times])

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to store how many lines are left to be read:

```py
infile = open('file.txt', 'r')

lines = []
lines_left = 0
for line in infile:
    # If there are any lines left to be read,
    # add the current line to lines and decrement
    # the remaining lines counter
    if lines_left > 0:
        lines.append(line)
        lines_left -= 1
        continue
    
    # If the expected line is found, add the
    # current line to lines and set how many lines
    # should be read in the next iterations of
    # the loop (in this case, 2)
    if line.startswith('X'):
        lines.append(line)
        lines_left = 2

infile.close()
```